# ubi-partman error 141 creating EFI partition (dual boot W10 different hard-drives)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in a separate hard drive from windows 10.

I have 50 Gb free space, I can create successfully the root, home, swap partitions but when I try to create the EFI system partition (in order to place here the bootloader) I get a ubi-partman code 141 error.

I have disabled secure boot and fast boot.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need another EFI partition. The one on the first drive (where Windows is supposedly installed) is the one that should be used. You can install Ubuntu anywhere else but EFI should be only one.

Comment: MichaelBay is correct; however, it also looks like this is a [known bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1302694) It may be related to a damaged partition table, so I'd proceed with caution. If the disk uses GPT, you might want to do a verification (`v` option) using `gdisk` to see what it says. Also, if your separate hard disk is an external or removable one, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721158/boot-problems-with-ubuntu-on-a-external-drive) for a potential pitfall.

Comment: you mean selecting my dev/sdb1/ Windows 10 loader? as device to install the bootloader? Wouldn't that interfere with my Windows installation. It is in the main SSD drive where Ubuntu Won't be installed.

Comment: Hi Rod, I will check if the disk is GPT. It's and internal HDD drive. I use a SSD of 128 Gb as main disk for W!0 and I wanted to install Ubuntu in 50 free Gb allocated in the secondary HDD.

Comment: Looking at other posts in this site, here it recommends to do it the other way around, setting the bootlader in the second drive where Ubuntu lives and then change the HDD boot priority. I'm confused about how to deal with it since I don't wanna mess my current W10 installation. https://askubuntu.com/questions/274371/install-on-second-hard-drive-with-startup-boot-option

Comment: I finally installed the bootloader in the same secondary disk where Ubuntu lives and everything ran fine except for the fact that I need to set nomodeset before starting it. Other don't that grub deals well booting both Ubuntu and W10 this way.